# Error in receiving data in C# client socket from java server socket

Tags: c#, java, serversocket

I am creating a Socket connection with C# client socket and Java Server Socket.
When i am  sending data from client socket,the server socket is properly receiving that data.
But when i am trying to send data back to Client socket from Server socket it is getting hanged on client side in receiving data.

Client Side Code(In C#.net)

```
           clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);

            string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
            System.Net.IPHostEntry hostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
            System.Net.IPAddress[] ipAddresses = hostEntry.AddressList;
            System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEP =
                new System.Net.IPEndPoint(ipAddresses[ipAddresses.Length - 1], port);
            clientSocket.Connect(remoteEP);
             string sendData = inputFilePath;
                    byte[] byteDataSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendData);
                    clientSocket.Send(byteDataSend);

                    int receivedBufferSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                    byte[] recivedData = new Byte[receivedBufferSize];
                    int receivedDataLength = clientSocket.Receive(recivedData);
                    string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recivedData, 0, receivedDataLength);
                    textFilePath = stringData;
                    Console.Write(stringData);
                    clientSocket.Close();
```

Server Socket Code (In Java)

```
           Socket connection = server.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); 
            fileName = in.readLine();
            convertedFile =runConverter.convertDocumet(fileName);
            byte[] sendingData = convertedFile.getBytes("US-ASCII");
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            dos.write(sendingData, 0, sendingData.length);
```

Tell me what is problem??
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem with that kind of c# code is the synchronous receive.
I always recommend doing an asynchronous read, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067969/net-networkstream-closed-how-to-be-sure-all-data-is-read/3111361#3111361).

I'm not positive that that's the source of your problem, but if you implemented the asynchronous receive with a bit of logging there's a good chance that that will either fix your problem or make it much more obvious as to what your problem is.

A hang on synchronous receive does suggest that the Java isn't sending data to the same socket that the c# is listening on, so double-checking those endpoints can also be a good idea.

Hope that helps!